# Filter on many-to-one model

Tags: python, django, filter, many-to-one

I want to be able assign users vehicle registrations, and when the user logs into the website their home page should have a list of vehicle regs they own.

However I cannot get the model class to filter on the foreign key.

views.py

```
@login_required   
def home(request):
    # This is the basic user landing Page
    veh_list = Vehicle.objects.filter(UserProfile.user)
    return render(request, 'portal/home.html', {"veh_list": veh_list})
```

model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This line is required. Links UserProfile to a User model instance.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    # The additional attributes we wish to include.
    compName = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    milkco = models.IntegerField()


    # Override the __unicode__() method to return out something meaningful!
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    vehid = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    company = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, default = 1)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "vehicle"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.vehid
```

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends 'portal/base.html' %}

{% block title %}{{user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }} Portal{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <p>This is the home Page</p>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h4>Optiload says... hello {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}!</h4>
    {% endif %}

    {% for veh in veh_list %}
        {{ veh}}
    {% endfor %}

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href="/logout/">Logout</a><br/>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Could someone help me with where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Does this work? `veh_list = Vehicle.objects.filter(company__user=request.user)`

Comment: @Sagar Yes.. that's exactly what I need.

Comment: I will add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Django offers a powerful and intuitive way to “follow” relationships in lookups, taking care of the SQL JOINs for you automatically, behind the scenes. To span a relationship, just use the field name of related fields across models, separated by double underscores, until you get to the field you want.

So your query should look like

```
veh_list = Vehicle.objects.filter(company__user=request.user)
```

[Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make queries with unnamed arguments:

`Vehicle.objects.filter(UserProfile.user)`

In this case you want:

`Vehicle.objects.filter(company=[your user])`